# How i can use stack weidget in grid view (in grid view i am passing the lsit of images)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gridview

**Gride vie code:**

```
GridView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
      itemCount: myCards.length,
      gridDelegate:
           SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                   mainAxisSpacing: 3, crossAxisCount: 3),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return myCards[index];},
      ),
```

**Result**
[image]

***What I want to achieve with stack weight in grid view:***

[image]

Comment: I added a new answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update answer Jan-31-2021**

Needed import

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Another approach: First define the list of cards and the space you want between cards.

```
  final double cardSpace = 20;

  final List<Widget> list = [
    Container(width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.red),
    Container(width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.blue),
    Container(width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.green),
    Container(width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.amber)
  ];
```

Then in inside you column, listview or wathever you have:

```
            Stack(children: [
                // Card Deck
                SizedBox(width: 50 + (list.length - 1) * cardSpace, height: 80),
                // Cards
                ...list
                    .mapIndexed((index, widget) => Positioned(
                        left: index * cardSpace,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            child: widget)))
                    .toList()
              ])
```

Result:

[image]

This way you can use and index with your list of cards.

---

Use Stack widget instead:

```
        Stack(
            children: [
              // Deck Size
              const SizedBox(width: 100),
              // Card 1
              Container(width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.red),
              // Card 2
              Positioned(
                  left: 20,
                  child:
                      Container(width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.blue)),
              // Card 3
              Positioned(
                  left: 40,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Container(
                      width: 50, height: 80, color: Colors.green)),
            ],
          ),
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have a list of images it did not work on `myCards[index];`

Comment: `...dealersCards.mapIndexed((index, Image) => Positioned`. I am getting error at .mapIndexed. This method is not defined for the List. My List is `List<Image> dealersCards = [];`. its empity list then i add images in it  `dealersCards.add(Image.asset(dealerSecondCard!),);`. Let me know where i am making mistake. I am waiting for your positive responce. **Thank you.**

Comment: Please import the following dependency: import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

Comment: Thank you for your help @Johan Ordenes Galleguillos